# How to fix the "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" or "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create zip list for the two different sets of list (id and email). But I'm keep getting an error saying: `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Here is an original script:

```
zlist = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(email_list, name_list)), columns=['email', 'id'])
```

I tried to change it to bracket from parenthesis within the line, but I get another error saying: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

This is the changed script:

```
zlist = pd.DataFrame(list(zip[email_list, name_list]), columns=['email', 'id'])
```

I used this same script for my prior projects without an issue. Does anyone know what may be the issue in my script? Or how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you assign `list` or `zip` to a numpy array somewhere earlier in your code?

Comment: Hi @9769953
Yes - and I used ldap feature when assigning list. 
`id_list = fdf['mro_eid'].tolist()` --->
`user_data = ldap.search_eids(id_list)` ---> `email_list = [user_email['mail'] for user_email in user_data]` --->
`name_list = [user_eid['cn'] for user_eid in user_data]` --->
`name_list = [name.lower() for name in name_list]`

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(list)); print(type(zip))`. Insert this line just before `zlist = pd.DataFrame(...)`

Comment: Hi @Corralien, I got <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and <class 'type'> when printing the line

Comment: This is your problem, you override `list` keyword. Do you have a line looks like `list = ...`? Use `lst` as variable name but not `list`

Comment: @Corralien, yes I do. `id_list = fdf['mro_eid'].tolist()` I have this already that allows me to list out all if the ids

Comment: No `id_list` but `list` only.

Comment: callable(list) should return True, if not you have overridden list somewhere prior,